# Image zoom on hover not working with :after

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I just want to add a zoom effect and transparent overlay into my image, I tried this way but working only the overlay. Image zoom effect isn't working. How can I fix this?

```css
.image-box img {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}

.image-box {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-box img:hover {
  transform:scale(1.1); 
}

.image-box:after {
  content: '\A';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}

.image-box:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner-box">
  <figure class="image-box">
    <img width="480" height="480" src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg">
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overlay itself prevents the hover event from propagating to the img.
One solution is to not use `:hover` on the img, but to grow the img on hovering the image-box.

```css
.image-box img{
 position: relative;
 transition: all 500ms ease;
}

.image-box{
 overflow: hidden;
}

.image-box:hover img{       /* changed */
 transform:scale(1.1); 
}

 .image-box:after{
    content:'\A';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
 height:100%;
    top:0;
 left:0;
  z-index: 2;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}

 .image-box:hover:after{
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner-box">
  <figure class="image-box">
    <img width="480" height="480" src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg">
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following class:

```
.image-box:hover img{
    transform:scale(1.1);
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}
```

```css
.image-box img{
    position: relative;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}
.image-box{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.image-box img:hover{
    transform:scale(1.1);
}
.image-box:after{
    content:'\A';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index: 2;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}
.image-box:hover:after{
    opacity:1;
}
.image-box:hover img{
    transform:scale(1.1);
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner-box">
      <figure class="image-box">
        <img width="480" height="480" src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg">
      </figure>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your demo works perfectly you just need a minor change in `.image-box:after`. I have updated `z-index` to -1.

```css
.image-box img {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}
.image-box {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image-box:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.image-box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}
.image-box:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner-box">
  <figure class="image-box">
    <img width="480" height="480" src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg">
  </figure>
</div>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: your solution is not fulfilling the original requirement. Requirement is to have an overlay over the image with zoom effect but your solution places the overlay behind the image and that is not needed, please read the requirement first before suggesting any solution.

Comment: @Ddmteetu I have gone through the requirement and I have misunderstood it. People do mistakes no one is perfect. As long as I see the author doesn't have any problem with it.